# What happens if the Maze spell is cast in Sigil?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes, planescape

I'm curious about casting the *Maze* spell in the city of Sigil....

In *Planescape: Adventures in the Multiverse* – *Sigil and the Outlands*, the "[Alterations to Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/paitm/sato/sigil-the-city-of-doors#AlterationstoMagic)" section states:

> ***Banishment.*** Effects that banish a target from Sigil treat the target as if Sigil were its home plane.

However, the [*Maze*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/maze) spell does not make any reference to a creature's "home plane" (and can a maze actually be a creature's home plane?). But the spell does say that "a minotaur or goristro demon automatically succeeds" (does that means that the Maze is treated as a "home plane" of these creatures?).

The "Alterations to Magic" section also states:

> ***Teleportation.*** Attempts to teleport into or out of Sigil fail, but such magic functions normally when used to teleport within the city.

*Maze* is a "banishment" spell, but is it considered "teleportation"?

In addition, the Lady of Pain can banish people into her own "mazes". I assume they are completely different than the Maze spell, since she is pretty much a "god" (or some other super power).

I'm curious how DMs would interpret the official rules regarding casting *Maze* in Sigil.

Comment: Minitaurs and Goristros are "good at mazes" which is why you can't trap them in one.

Comment: @Jabbamonkey The Lady's mazes are, indeed, very different to those created by the maze spell - they contain looping repeated duplicates of the physical environment  you were in when she used the ability instead of being made of planes of force, they're harder to escape, and beings trapped in them have their physical needs provided for. Also, do _not_ call her a god, lest her shadow fall upon you.

Comment: Nice try, but I think calling the Lady of Pain "pretty much a 'god'" is pretty much tantamount to calling the Lady of Pain a god.  To the maze with you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### The spell works normally, except that in the maze you are under the same restrictions as if you were in Sigil

[Maze](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/maze) in 5e is a banishment effect that sends you to a demiplane.

> You banish a creature that you can see within range into a labyrinthine demiplane.

The same section you cite says about demiplanes:

> **Extradimensional Space**. Extradimensional spaces, **demiplanes**, and pocket dimensions—such as those created by a bag of holding or the rope trick spell—function within Sigil, but those spaces follow all these restrictions as if they were part of the city.

That is, the *maze* spell will work normally, but you cannot *plane shift* out of the demiplane created by the spell to escape Sigil, because you cannot *plane shift* out of Sigil, as stated in the same section

> **Planar Travel**. Effects that allow interplanar travel, such as astral projection or plane shift, fail if used to try to enter or leave Sigil

---

P.S. It is neccesary to have this rule for extraplanar spaces, or they would provide a loophole to escape Sigil by magical means: a demiplane normally is not part of the plane where it is created. There is an entry in the *Sage Advice Compendium* for it:

> **Are extradimensional spaces, such as a demiplane or the space created by rope trick, considered to be on a different plane of existence?** An extradimensional space (aka an extraplanar space) is outside other planes. Therefore, if you’re on the Material Plane and your foe is in an extradimensional space, the two of you aren’t on the same plane of existence.

In the cosmology of 5e, demiplanes are located in the Deep Ethereal. The *PHB* and *DMG* do not say where they are, but the Xill monster entry in *Mordenkainen's Fiendish Folio* does:

> **Deep within the Ethereal Plane are the demiplanes**, miniature worlds built by powerful archmages and other mighty entities to serve as a private domain.

So by default, putting a creature into the Maze removes them from Sigil, putting them in a demiplane somewhere in the Deep Ethereal. Normally, once you are there, you then could use an effect like *plane shift* to travel to any plane you have a tuning fork for, because that demiplane or the Deep Ethereal normally have none of the  restrictions Sigil has. The special rule makes it so that the *do* have those same restrictions, and you cannot escape.

Answer (score 8):

The creature's "home plane" is for use with the spell titled Banishment, which reads:

> If the target is native to the plane of existence you're on, you banish the target to a harmless demiplane. [...]
>
> If the target is native to a different plane of existence than the one you're on, the target is banished with a faint popping noise, returning to its home plane. [...]

The purpose of the text is to prevent Banishment from being an easy way out of Sigil.

Maze doesn't interact with a target's home plane at all, and therefore doesn't care about that text. It works the same whether it's cast on Sigil or anywhere else.

Teleportation and Banishment are generally regarded as separate effects. Again, the point is that you can't easily leave Sigil (except through interacting with the portals). It's not trying to nerf spells that lock you down.

Comment: What if you get mazed and use plane shift from the maze?

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin An interesting question, that goes beyond my memory of how everything works. I think at one point demiplanes of the type created by maze were "within" their parent plane (so: subject to the rules of Sigil), but I'm not sure if that applies to this setting/edition/spell/etc.